# Deserializing JSON creates another attribute in the table and doesn't return data correctly

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm currently trying to connect to my MySQL database, "CoffeeShop" with SpringBoot and return all records in the "menu" table. But the issue is that it returns the number of records, but only the first record, repeated 4 times (4 records in the table) and adds another "primary_id" key to the table

This is how my "menu" table appears in MySQL:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price      | double           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| size       | varchar(126)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | varchar(126)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

THIS is how the table appears after making a call to the page:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price      | double           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| size       | varchar(126)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | varchar(126)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Notice the new attribute "product_id", this is a by-product of why the JSON returning is in the format I mentioned in the beginning.

This is the Menu class I'm using to represent each record:

```
@Entity
public class Menu {

    @Id
    private Integer productId;

    private String name;

    private Double price;

    private String size;

    private String type;

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    @JsonSetter("product id")
    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    //And the rest of the setters/getters omitted...
}
```

This is the "CrudRepository" I'm using

```
public interface MenuRepository extends CrudRepository<Menu, Integer> {
    
}
```

This is the contents of my "application.properties" file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverclassname = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/CoffeeShop
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

This is the Controller I use for the request:

```
@RestController
public class MenuController {
    
    @Autowired
    private MenuRepository menuRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/menu")
    public Iterable<Menu> getFullMenu(){
        return  menuRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the issue is because the fields have different names (space), so when creating the table JPA is thinking they are different fields.

My suggestion here would be instead of using the `Menu` class as the entity and the response, you split it in two different classes.
It would avoid the mix of your exposed data with you inside data. In this specific case when doing that, you won't need that `@JsonSetter` annotation in the entity class, it would be places in the DTO class.

See: https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Also this might help you: [Spring Boot @ManyToOne only Id @JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357405/spring-boot-manytoone-only-id-jsonproperty)