# How to send only Id foreign key in POST request via JSON?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I make internet shoe shop and now I create REST Controller for its goods, so now I'm testing POST request and I have relation to good's manufacturer with manufacturerId
[image: DB Architecture]
But now I need to write all information about manufacturer into JSON, but I think it's not a good practice to act like that.

Good entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "goods")
public class Good {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //@JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

//    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
//    @Column(name = "sex")
//    private sexType sexType;

    @Column(name = "sex")
    private String sex;

    /**
     * proved and it actually works!
     */
    //@JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "ManufacturerId")
    //@JsonIgnoreProperties
    Manufacturer manufacturer; //Many goods can refer to one manufacturer


    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "good")//Uni-directional reference to size array
    List<Size> sizes;
```

Manufacturer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manufacturers")
public class Manufacturer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ManufacturerName")
    private String manufacturerName;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "Telephone")
    private String telephone;

    //@JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE},
            mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Good> goods;
```

JSON example for POST request:

```
  {
    "title": "Model",
    "sex": "CHILD",
    "manufacturer": {
      "id": 1,
      "manufacturerName": "Ralf",
      "address": "Moscow",
      "telephone": "9-999-999-99-99"
    },
    "sizes": [
      {
        "size": 37,
        "quantity": 5
      },
      {
        "size": 39,
        "quantity": 4
      }
    ]
  }
```

How can I send only manufacturerId?

If I use `@JsonIgnore` annotatinon, I think I won't get additional info about manufacturer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot @ManyToOne only Id @JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357405/spring-boot-manytoone-only-id-jsonproperty)

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement link using hateoas.  Here is a sample request data.

```
{
"title": "Model",
"sex": "CHILD",
"manufacturer": 
            "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "/manufacturers/1"
            }
        },
"sizes": [
  {
    "size": 37,
    "quantity": 5
  },
  {
    "size": 39,
    "quantity": 4
  }
]
```

}
Now no need to provide all Manufacturer fields in request data, instead you need to provide only id/

Comment: Actually now it creates new manufacturer w/o reference to already existing